# How to determine if SharePoint is in Debug mode?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, debugging, uls

My SharePoint was choking on bad code in a feature.  The VS12 debugger popped up and asked me if I wanted to enable debugging, and that it would update the web.config.

Well, I would like to turn off debugging now, and have followed the advice listed here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231550.aspx stating:

> To reverse the changes and disable debugging, change the following XML in the web.config file:
>
> - Turn off the call stack (CallStack="false")
> - Enable custom errors in Visual Studio ()
> - Disable compilation debugging ()

I have checked and all webapps in the VirtualDirectories have the above changes. I have performed an iisrestart.  But still I am seeing tons of ULS messages with "DEBUG" in them.

Oddly they all are of Category "Upgrade".  Here are a few:

```
06/04/2014 20:34:33.50  w3wp.exe (0x10F4)   0x2B84  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajy5i   High    06/04/2014 20:34:33.50 w3wp (0x10F4) 0x2B84 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade PSDatabaseSequence ajy5i DEBUG Returning SchemaVersion [15.1.106.0] for Database ProjectServer_Consolidate, Status = Online. 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965
06/04/2014 20:34:33.50  w3wp.exe (0x10F4)   0x2B84  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajxmk   High    06/04/2014 20:34:33.50 w3wp (0x10F4) 0x2B84 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPUpgradeSession ajxmk DEBUG IsBackwardsCompatible [ProjectDatabase Name=ProjectServer_Consolidate] returned: True. 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965  46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965
06/04/2014 20:34:33.51  w3wp.exe (0x10F4)   0x2B84  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyys   High    06/04/2014 20:34:33.51 w3wp (0x10F4) 0x2B84 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyys DEBUG Delegate [Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.ForceDatabaseUpgradeSequence] returned not applicable for [ProjectDatabase Name=ProjectWebAppTest]. 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965  46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965
06/04/2014 20:34:33.51  w3wp.exe (0x10F4)   0x2B84  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyys   High    06/04/2014 20:34:33.51 w3wp (0x10F4) 0x2B84 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyys DEBUG Delegate [Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.PublishedDatabaseSequence] returned not applicable for [ProjectDatabase Name=ProjectWebAppTest]. 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965
06/04/2014 20:34:33.51  w3wp.exe (0x10F4)   0x2B84  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyys   High    06/04/2014 20:34:33.51 w3wp (0x10F4) 0x2B84 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyys DEBUG Delegate [Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.ReportingDatabaseSequence] returned not applicable for [ProjectDatabase Name=ProjectWebAppTest]. 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965
06/04/2014 20:34:33.51  w3wp.exe (0x10F4)   0x2B84  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyys   High    06/04/2014 20:34:33.51 w3wp (0x10F4) 0x2B84 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyys DEBUG Delegate [Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.VersionsDatabaseSequence] returned not applicable for [ProjectDatabase Name=ProjectWebAppTest]. 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965  46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965
06/04/2014 20:34:33.51  w3wp.exe (0x10F4)   0x2B84  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyys   High    06/04/2014 20:34:33.51 w3wp (0x10F4) 0x2B84 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyys DEBUG Delegate [Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.WorkingDatabaseSequence] returned not applicable for [ProjectDatabase Name=ProjectWebAppTest]. 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965   46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965
06/04/2014 20:34:33.53  w3wp.exe (0x10F4)   0x2B84  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajy5i   High    06/04/2014 20:34:33.53 w3wp (0x10F4) 0x2B84 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade PSDatabaseSequence ajy5i DEBUG Returning SchemaVersion [15.1.106.0] for Database ProjectWebAppTest, Status = Online. 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965
06/04/2014 20:34:33.53  w3wp.exe (0x10F4)   0x2B84  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajy5i   High    06/04/2014 20:34:33.53 w3wp (0x10F4) 0x2B84 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade PSDatabaseSequence ajy5i DEBUG Returning SchemaVersion [15.1.106.0] for Database ProjectWebAppTest, Status = Online. 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965
06/04/2014 20:34:33.53  w3wp.exe (0x10F4)   0x2B84  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyxg   High    06/04/2014 20:34:33.53 w3wp (0x10F4) 0x2B84 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade PSDatabaseSequence ajyxg DEBUG UpgradableBuildBypassInternal = 0 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965
06/04/2014 20:34:33.53  w3wp.exe (0x10F4)   0x2B84  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyxh   High    06/04/2014 20:34:33.53 w3wp (0x10F4) 0x2B84 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade PSDatabaseSequence ajyxh DEBUG UpgradableBuildBypass = 0 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965
06/04/2014 20:34:33.53  w3wp.exe (0x10F4)   0x2B84  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajxmf   High    06/04/2014 20:34:33.53 w3wp (0x10F4) 0x2B84 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPUpgradeSession ajxmf DEBUG CanUpgrade [ProjectDatabase Name=ProjectWebAppTest] returned: True. 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965
06/04/2014 20:34:33.53  w3wp.exe (0x10F4)   0x2B84  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajy5i   High    06/04/2014 20:34:33.53 w3wp (0x10F4) 0x2B84 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade PSDatabaseSequence ajy5i DEBUG Returning SchemaVersion [15.1.106.0] for Database ProjectWebAppTest, Status = Online. 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965
06/04/2014 20:34:33.53  w3wp.exe (0x10F4)   0x2B84  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajxmx   High    06/04/2014 20:34:33.53 w3wp (0x10F4) 0x2B84 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPUpgradeSession ajxmx DEBUG NeedsUpgrade [ProjectDatabase Name=ProjectWebAppTest] returned: False. 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965  46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965
06/04/2014 20:34:33.53  w3wp.exe (0x10F4)   0x2B84  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajy5i   High    06/04/2014 20:34:33.53 w3wp (0x10F4) 0x2B84 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade PSDatabaseSequence ajy5i DEBUG Returning SchemaVersion [15.1.106.0] for Database ProjectWebAppTest, Status = Online. 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965
06/04/2014 20:34:33.53  w3wp.exe (0x10F4)   0x2B84  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajxmx   High    06/04/2014 20:34:33.53 w3wp (0x10F4) 0x2B84 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPUpgradeSession ajxmx DEBUG NeedsUpgrade [ProjectDatabase Name=ProjectWebAppTest] returned: False. 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965  46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965
06/04/2014 20:34:33.53  w3wp.exe (0x10F4)   0x2B84  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyw6   High    06/04/2014 20:34:33.53 w3wp (0x10F4) 0x2B84 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPHierarchyManager ajyw6 DEBUG [SPTree Value=ProjectDatabase Name=ProjectWebAppTest] added to dependency cache by lookup 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965
06/04/2014 20:34:33.53  w3wp.exe (0x10F4)   0x2B84  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade alz7g   High    06/04/2014 20:34:33.53 w3wp (0x10F4) 0x2B84 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade PSDatabaseSequence alz7g DEBUG ProjectDatabaseSequence.AddNextLevelObjects() ... 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965 46c4979c-a9e7-404b-9f46-310fdaa28965

06/04/2014 20:23:15.53  w3wp.exe (0x29C0)   0x3434  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/04/2014 20:23:15.53 w3wp (0x29C0) 0x3434 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Upgrade.SearchAnalyticsReportingDatabaseSequence] for [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchAnalyticsReportingDatabase], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 10. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  
06/04/2014 20:23:15.53  w3wp.exe (0x29C0)   0x3434  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/04/2014 20:23:15.53 w3wp (0x29C0) 0x3434 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Upgrade.SearchGathererDatabaseSequence] for [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchGathererDatabase], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 10. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  
06/04/2014 20:23:15.53  w3wp.exe (0x29C0)   0x3434  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/04/2014 20:23:15.53 w3wp (0x29C0) 0x3434 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Upgrade.SearchLinksDatabaseSequence] for [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchLinksDatabase], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 10. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    
06/04/2014 20:23:15.53  w3wp.exe (0x29C0)   0x3434  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/04/2014 20:23:15.53 w3wp (0x29C0) 0x3434 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Upgrade.SearchServiceSequence] for [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 10. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 
06/04/2014 20:23:15.53  w3wp.exe (0x29C0)   0x3434  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/04/2014 20:23:15.53 w3wp (0x29C0) 0x3434 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Upgrade.SearchServiceSequence2] for [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPrejoinedFarm], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 10. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000   
06/04/2014 20:23:15.53  w3wp.exe (0x29C0)   0x3434  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/04/2014 20:23:15.53 w3wp (0x29C0) 0x3434 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Upgrade.SearchServiceApplicationSequence] for [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 10. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  
06/04/2014 20:23:15.53  w3wp.exe (0x29C0)   0x3434  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/04/2014 20:23:15.53 w3wp (0x29C0) 0x3434 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Upgrade.ServerSequence] for [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServer], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 10. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  
06/04/2014 20:23:15.53  w3wp.exe (0x29C0)   0x3434  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/04/2014 20:23:15.53 w3wp (0x29C0) 0x3434 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Upgrade.SiteSequence] for [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 10. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

The farm seems to be going slower than before, and all these ULS messages with DEBUG make me suspicious.

Is there anything that I might be forgetting to completely turn off debugging?

Thank you!

====================

UPDATE:  After ensuring that the registry did not have the 'EnableDiagnistics' dregword set (it is set to 0) and restarting the server, I still see many messages that contain DEBUG in them.  This leads me to believe that debugging is still enabled even after updating all web.config files as suggested in the above link.

```
06/05/2014 11:26:56.63  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:56.63 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Upgrade.SessionStateSharedResourceProvider12Sequence] for [Microsoft.Office.Server.Upgrade.SharedResourceProvider12], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 3. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    
06/05/2014 11:26:56.63  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:56.63 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Upgrade.StateServiceSequence] for [Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.StateService], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 3. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 
06/05/2014 11:26:56.63  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyd   High    06/05/2014 11:26:56.63 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyd DEBUG End registering Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000   
06/05/2014 11:26:56.63  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyx8   High    06/05/2014 11:26:56.63 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyx8 DEBUG Begin registering Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    
06/05/2014 11:26:56.63  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyya   High    06/05/2014 11:26:56.63 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyya DEBUG No assembly manifest found. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    
06/05/2014 11:26:56.76  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:56.76 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Upgrade.UserProfileFarmSequence] for [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm], Phase: 0, Order: 17. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000   
06/05/2014 11:26:56.76  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:56.76 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Upgrade.ProfileDatabaseSequence] for [Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ProfileDatabase], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 17. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  
06/05/2014 11:26:56.76  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:56.76 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Upgrade.UserProfileServerSequence] for [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServer], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 17. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  
06/05/2014 11:26:56.76  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:56.76 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Upgrade.SocialDatabaseSequence] for [Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SocialDatabase], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 17. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    
06/05/2014 11:26:56.76  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:56.76 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Upgrade.UserProfileApplicationSequence] for [Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 17. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    
06/05/2014 11:26:56.76  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyd   High    06/05/2014 11:26:56.76 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyd DEBUG End registering Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  
06/05/2014 11:26:56.76  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyx8   High    06/05/2014 11:26:56.76 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyx8 DEBUG Begin registering Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  
06/05/2014 11:26:56.76  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyya   High    06/05/2014 11:26:56.76 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyya DEBUG No assembly manifest found. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    
06/05/2014 11:26:57.07  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.07 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Upgrade.SearchAdminDatabaseSequence] for [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchAdminDatabase], Phase: 0, Order: 10. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 
06/05/2014 11:26:57.07  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.07 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Upgrade.SearchAnalyticsReportingDatabaseSequence] for [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchAnalyticsReportingDatabase], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 10. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  
06/05/2014 11:26:57.07  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.07 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Upgrade.SearchGathererDatabaseSequence] for [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchGathererDatabase], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 10. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  
06/05/2014 11:26:57.07  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.07 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Upgrade.SearchLinksDatabaseSequence] for [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchLinksDatabase], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 10. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    
06/05/2014 11:26:57.07  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.07 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Upgrade.SearchServiceSequence] for [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 10. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 
06/05/2014 11:26:57.07  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.07 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Upgrade.SearchServiceSequence2] for [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPrejoinedFarm], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 10. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000   
06/05/2014 11:26:57.07  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.07 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Upgrade.SearchServiceApplicationSequence] for [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 10. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  
06/05/2014 11:26:57.07  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.07 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Upgrade.ServerSequence] for [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServer], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 10. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  
06/05/2014 11:26:57.07  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.07 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Upgrade.SiteSequence] for [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 10. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 
06/05/2014 11:26:57.07  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyd   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.07 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyd DEBUG End registering Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    
06/05/2014 11:26:57.07  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyx8   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.07 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyx8 DEBUG Begin registering Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  
06/05/2014 11:26:57.07  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyya   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.07 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyya DEBUG No assembly manifest found. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    
06/05/2014 11:26:57.10  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.10 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.Upgrade.PowerPivotMidTierServiceInstanceSequence] for [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.MidTierServiceInstance], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 11. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000   
06/05/2014 11:26:57.10  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.10 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.Upgrade.PowerPivotMidTierServiceProxySequence] for [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.MidTierServiceProxy], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 11. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 
06/05/2014 11:26:57.10  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.10 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.Upgrade.PowerPivotMidTierServiceSequence] for [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.MidTierService], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 11. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000   
06/05/2014 11:26:57.10  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.10 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.Upgrade.PowerPivotServiceApplicationProxySequence] for [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.GeminiServiceApplicationProxy], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 11. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000   
06/05/2014 11:26:57.10  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.10 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.Upgrade.PowerPivotServiceApplicationSequence] for [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.GeminiServiceApplication], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 11. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 
06/05/2014 11:26:57.10  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.10 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.Upgrade.PowerPivotServiceDatabaseSequence] for [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.GeminiServiceDatabase], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 11. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000   
06/05/2014 11:26:57.10  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyd   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.10 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyd DEBUG End registering Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    
06/05/2014 11:26:57.10  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyx8   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.10 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyx8 DEBUG Begin registering Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.Upgrade, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000   
06/05/2014 11:26:57.10  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyya   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.10 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyya DEBUG No assembly manifest found. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    
06/05/2014 11:26:57.10  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.10 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.Upgrade.PPSFarmSequence] for [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 5. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 
06/05/2014 11:26:57.16  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.16 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.BIMonitoringServiceApplicationSequence] for [Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.BIMonitoringServiceApplication], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 5. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 
06/05/2014 11:26:57.16  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.16 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.Upgrade.PPSDatabaseSequence] for [Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.BIMonitoringServiceDatabase], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 5. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  
06/05/2014 11:26:57.16  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyd   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.16 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyd DEBUG End registering Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.Upgrade, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 
06/05/2014 11:26:57.16  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyx8   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.16 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyx8 DEBUG Begin registering Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 
06/05/2014 11:26:57.16  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyya   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.16 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyya DEBUG No assembly manifest found. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    
06/05/2014 11:26:57.18  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.18 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.Upgrade.SecureStoreDatabaseSequence] for [Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.SecureStoreServiceDatabase], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 17. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    
06/05/2014 11:26:57.18  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyp   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.18 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.Upgrade.SecureStoreServiceApplicationSequence] for [Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.SecureStoreServiceApplication], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 17. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000   
06/05/2014 11:26:57.18  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyyd   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.18 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyd DEBUG End registering Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000   
06/05/2014 11:26:57.18  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyx8   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.18 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyx8 DEBUG Begin registering Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.Upgrade, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 
06/05/2014 11:26:57.18  w3wp.exe (0x08AC)   0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation   Upgrade ajyya   High    06/05/2014 11:26:57.18 w3wp (0x08AC) 0x16F0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyya DEBUG No assembly manifest found. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    


06/05/2014 11:36:47.42  w3wp.exe (0x08EC)   0x06D0  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  ac2zs   Verbose Write Debug Scope start event Request (GET:http://mysite:80/default.aspx) Id:7212751394963456 Parent ID:-1  e7f7979c-d982-404b-9f46-3d2f23d057a1
06/05/2014 11:36:47.42  w3wp.exe (0x08EC)   0x06D0  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  ac2zs   Verbose Write Debug Scope start event BeginRequestHandler Id:7212751394963459 Parent ID:7212751394963456    e7f7979c-d982-404b-9f46-3d2f23d057a1
06/05/2014 11:36:47.44  w3wp.exe (0x08EC)   0x06D0  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  ac2zt   Verbose Write Debug Scope End event BeginRequestHandler Id:7212751394963459 e7f7979c-d982-404b-9f46-3d2f23d057a1
06/05/2014 11:36:47.44  w3wp.exe (0x08EC)   0x06D0  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  ac2zs   Verbose Write Debug Scope start event PreSendRequestHeaders Id:7212751394963460 Parent ID:7212751394963456  e7f7979c-d982-404b-9f46-3d2f23d057a1
06/05/2014 11:36:47.44  w3wp.exe (0x08EC)   0x06D0  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  ac2zt   Verbose Write Debug Scope End event PreSendRequestHeaders Id:7212751394963460   e7f7979c-d982-404b-9f46-3d2f23d057a1
06/05/2014 11:36:47.44  w3wp.exe (0x08EC)   0x06D0  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  ac2zs   Verbose Write Debug Scope start event EndRequestHandler SharePointEndRequest Id:7212751394963461 Parent ID:7212751394963456 e7f7979c-d982-404b-9f46-3d2f23d057a1
```

Does something need to happen in VS?  Do I need to reset the Monitoring and Diagnostic services in CA?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

These are normal messages to see when we have a process load SharePoint binaries (be it owstimer, w3wp, or PowerShell). It does not mean SharePoint is in "debug mode".

These are simply debug *messages* letting you know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

there are two steps to enable or disable it.

1. Disable it from the Web Applications's web.config file

```
<SafeMode MaxControls="200" CallStack="false" ...>

<customErrors mode="On" />


<compilation batch="false" debug="false">
```

1. Now Disable / enable it in Layout Folders, which is located in 15/12/14 hives folder...C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Layouts...`<customErrors mode="On" />`

Try above steps and then test it.
http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1115

Comment: According to this link [link](http://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2013/01/11/debugging-sharepoint-2010-_layout-pages-and-turn-off-custom-errors/) the second step you mention turns off the friendly messages and does not effect debuggin.

Comment: did you try add a registry entry which is mentioned in the article at the end. make sure value should be 0.

Comment: I did not try adding the registry entry for debugging.  I just allowed visual studio to enable debugging.  But I will check there to see if the registry has been modified for debugging.

Comment: according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231550.aspx : [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\SharePointTools]
If the "EnableDiagnostics" REG_DWORD value does not already exist, create it manually. Set the “EnableDiagnostics” value to "1." 
Well, this word isnt there... not sure where else to look...

Comment: i would recommend, create the entry and put the value 0  then reboot the server & test it.

Comment: Just performed the restart of server after setting value of 0 in registry.  Still seeing many messages in ULS that contain 'DEBUG' within the Message. Ex
    06/05/2014 11:21:24.16 DistributedCacheService (0x008C) 0x09A0 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceSequence] for [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 1. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000